# What is means proxy gai_error=0?

Tags: android, database, http, error-handling, proxy

I am new on programming and mobile app developing.
I try to use http json for database but i have error again and again, so I wonder why I am getting this error.
Before the solition ,I want to learn this error.
What is means?
Thanks for your answers and sorry if there is my error.